# About rsync server and client

Tags: backup, vpn, rsync

after reading some documentation, I still don't get it (though it seems some just use it wrong):
What's the purpose of rsync server and why not using the client only? Most seem to use rsync via ssh, that's the client I suppose. Generally I thought, a server delivers and a client recieves, but in the freenas documentation, its described vice versa:

> the rsync server: this system pulls (receives) the data. This system is referred to as PULL in the configuration examples.
>
> the rsync client: this system pushes (sends) the data. This system is referred to as PUSH in the configuration examples.

Is that the normal setup? It confuses me, because in normal client-server-setup the client is the one that *pulls* the data, or not? So, if the server here is acting like a client, why are people using the rsync in client mode then to get (*pull*) files over ssh (as like most tutorials explain)?

How do I set this up then, when I have two storages in different networks (one for backup behind VPN for instance) and I don't want to run an extra sshd? Where is the server running and where the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in the client server model, the server has the content, and the client wants to obtain it, therefor, the client is pulling.

In the rsync model, the client is looking to archive local data, so it pushes it to the server. When you configure the server to obtain data from a client, it will pull that information in, to create archives.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's how I thought and so why I was confused.

Comment: I think you need to divorce yourself from the idea of pushing and pulling, think more about what role they play. Servers tend to be central data repositories in both push and pull models, clients tend to want to obtain or modify that data.

Answer (score 0):

The normal use-case for an rsync-server is as a service on the internet, so you can use the rsync-protcol to download just the changed files.

In this case there is no ssh-tunnel. I did see this often on mirrors. There the server provides a read-only-access via direct rsync-protocol.

The client connects to the server using that protocol.

In this case your world is "normal" again.